# All taxonomy terms of a specific depth

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

On a Drupal 7 site I have a view with a bunch of exposed filters (using Views + BEF) for taxonomies. Some of these taxonomies have terms with different depths. Is there a way I can dynamically show only the values of a specific depth? For example, one filter would have the depth 0 terms, another would have just the depth 1 terms.

I know that I can use "Limit list to selected items" and manually do it, but that feels clunky and requires more maintenance as terms are added. I also tried playing around with simple hierarchical select without success.

Is there some way of achieving this without manually adding terms to the exposed filter option list?

Answer (score 1):

In the Views filters, there are 2 default filters for taxonomy. You want to use *Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)*, then select the vocabulary and depth of the terms to include.

Comment: Tried that and the exposed list still includes all terms. The depth seems to impact what it should match (i.e. should a node containing a child be included when a parent is selected) but not the visible options in list.

Comment: You can select the terms from your tags to include in the filter options. You could also try to export the view and modify the filter programatically.